# jQuery will not work after Ajax reloads content (.bind)

Tags: jquery

for some reason my jQuery stops working after content is changed using ajax (different script will change the content and on mouse hover this JS should execute) here is my code is this something wrong my JS code? Or should I keep looking into Ajax code?

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function ($) {

    //get IE version
    function ieVersion() {
        var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
        if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
            var ua = navigator.userAgent;
            var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
            if (re.exec(ua) != null) rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
        }
        return rv;
    }

    //read href attr in a tag

    function readHref() {
        var result = arguments[0].replace(EM.QuickShop.BASE_URL, '');
        var patn = /catalog\/product\/view\/id\/(.*?)\//i;
        if (patn.test(result)) {
        var s = patn.exec(result);
        result = 'catalog/product/view/id/' +  s[1];
        } else {
        result = result.replace(/\//gi,"_!_");
        }
        return result;
    }

    //string trim
    function strTrim() {
        return arguments[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    }

    // quickshop init
    function _qsJnit() {
        var selectorObj = arguments[0];
        var listprod = $(selectorObj.itemClass);    // selector chon tat ca cac li chua san pham tren luoi
        var mypath = 'quickshop/index/view/path/';
        var baseUrl = EM.QuickShop.BASE_URL + mypath;

        var _qsHref = "<a id=\"em_quickshop_handler\" href=\"#\" style=\"visibility:hidden;position:absolute;top:0;left:0\"><span><span>"+EM.QuickShop.QS_TEXT+"</span></span></a>";
        $(document.body).append(_qsHref);
        var qsHandlerImg = $('#em_quickshop_handler img');

        $.each(listprod, function (index, value) {
            var reloadurl = baseUrl;

            //get reload url
            var prodLinkTag = $(value).find(selectorObj.aClass);
            if (!prodLinkTag || prodLinkTag.length == 0) return;
            var prodHref = readHref(prodLinkTag.attr('href'));
            reloadurl = baseUrl + prodHref;

            // show quickshop handle when hover product image
            $(selectorObj.imgClass, this).bind('mouseover', function () {
                var o = $(this).offset();
                $('#em_quickshop_handler').attr('href', reloadurl).show().css({
                        'top': o.top+($(this).height() - EM.QuickShop.QS_BTN_HEIGHT)/2+'px',
                        'left': o.left+($(this).width() - EM.QuickShop.QS_BTN_WIDTH)/2-4+'px',
                        'visibility': 'visible',
                        'z-index':  999
                });
            });
            $(value).bind('mouseout', function () {
                $('#em_quickshop_handler').hide();
            });
        });

        //fix bug image disapper when hover
        $('#em_quickshop_handler').bind('mouseover', function () {
            $(this).show();
        }).bind('click', function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });

        //insert quickshop popup
        $('#em_quickshop_handler').fancybox({
            'width': EM.QuickShop.QS_FRM_WIDTH,
            'height': EM.QuickShop.QS_FRM_HEIGHT,
            'autoScale': false,
            //'padding': 20,
            //'margin': 20,
            //'transitionIn'        : 'none',
            //'transitionOut'       : 'none',
            'type': 'iframe',
            onComplete: function () {
                $.fancybox.showActivity();
                $('#fancybox-frame').unbind('load');
                $('#fancybox-frame').bind('load', function () {
                    $.fancybox.hideActivity();
                });
            }
        });
    }

    if (typeof EM_QUICKSHOP_DISABLED == 'undefined' || !EM_QUICKSHOP_DISABLED)
        _qsJnit({
            itemClass: '.products-grid li.item, .products-list li.item, li.item .cate_product, .product-upsell-slideshow li.item, .mini-products-list li.item, #crosssell-products-list li.item', //selector for each items in catalog product list,use to insert quickshop image
            aClass: 'a.product-image', //selector for each a tag in product items,give us href for one product
            imgClass: '.product-image img' //class for quickshop href
        });
});
```

Comment: Use the delegated version of `on` instead of `bind`. You will have about 10 answers saying that shortly as it is a very common problem :) If you also showed some sample HTML you would have 11 answers, but too busy to do the typing myself right now!

Comment: That's because you have to re-initialize your code on your selectors after the ajax call,

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie why html is important here? ` $(selectorObj.imgClass, this).bind('mouseover', function () { ` changing this bind to on should work isn't? I will try now

Comment: Example html is only important if you want *working* answers :) Questions from new users get very little attention, so you will want to make it easier for them to help. A JSFiddle with your code and sample HTML will help everyone (including you) :)

Comment: You need to work out your jQuery element selectors in order to use delegated `on`. I cannot figure it out just looking at your code as it is a little obscure. Can you *please* provide sample html from an actual page :)

Answer (score -2):

put the event handler function inside $(document).ready(function(){...}). it shall work now

Comment: I think using .on is a better idea looking on how to implement it now, Also I think that ajax will not fire document ready

Comment: -1: This should have been a comment, but is completely wrong anyway as the existing code *is* in a document load event (just not the one you recognize): `jQuery(function ($){...});` is another jQuery syntax for on document ready.

Comment: NO! NO! NO! @TrueBlueAussie!!
What @InformatikBabo posted is completely right!! 
Learn Javascript before you say such things!

Comment: @sexyboy... "NO! NO! NO! don't make it so". The code shown is not an IIFE, it is a jQuery document load handler. `jQuery(function ($){...});` is the same as `$(function(){...});`. Suggest *you* learn jQuery before you jump in. :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie ÄH SEICH! I think you talk about a completely different topic. isch ja nöd zum glaube...

Comment: @sexyboy: I will say it again slowly and clearly for you: `The... existing... code... is... already... wrapped... in... a... jQuery... document... ready... handler...` There is no trailing `()`, so it is not an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE). Got it? **This answer is wrong** because it suggests adding another document ready handler **when it already has one**. :)